# Push Notifications on Apple Watch Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

I am trying to set FCM notification to my watch os project. This project is a stand-alone watch app that doesn’t have any iPhone interface.
I have integrated Firebase yet it’s not showing any notifications on the watch.

This is my code

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {

    FirebaseApp.configure()
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, _ in
          if granted {
            WKExtension.shared().registerForRemoteNotifications()
          }
        }
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    WKExtension.shared().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

 func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        // Handle the message received from the Watch app.
        let text = message["text"] as? String ?? ""
        print("Received message: \(text)")
        
        // Construct the reply message.
        let replyMessage = ["reply": "Thanks for the message!"]
        replyHandler(replyMessage)
    }

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        // Handle the message received from the iOS app.
        let text = message["reply"] as? String ?? ""
        print("Received reply: \(text)")
    }

// MessagingDelegate
    func messaging(_: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken ?? "")")
        
        UserInfo.setInfo(withValue: fcmToken ?? "", andKey: .fcmToken)
        
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "watch") { error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error:" + error.debugDescription)
                return
            }
            print("Successfully subscribed to topic")
        }
    }
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingDelegate) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.description)")
    }
    
    
    func didRegisterForRemoteNotifications(withDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        
        // Convert token to string
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }.joined()
        print("[WATCH PUSH NOTIFICACTIONS] Device Token: \(deviceTokenString)")
        
        Messaging.messaging().token { token, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching FCM registration token: \(error)")
            } else if let token = token {
                print("FCM registration token: \(token)")
            }
        }
        
        // UserSettings.shared.deviceToken = deviceTokenString
    }
```

I tried sending notifications from Postman and in Postman it’s showing notification sent yet it’s not visible in the watch app. I double-checked Firebase settings, and they are perfect as I have an iPhone app added in the same Firebase project, which is working perfectly and getting notifications. One more thing since it has a watch kit extension I tried with both google plist files with such as “**io.watchrx.watch.watchkitapp.watchkitextension**” and “**io.watchrx.watch.watchkitapp**” and still didn’t receive any notification. This is Postman payload that I am using

> {   "notification": {
> "data": {
> "questionId": 26354,
> "messageType": "textMessage",
> "question": "Test-Message",
> "answer": "[]",
> "caregiverName": "Test"
> }   },   "content_available": true,   "to": "fzw4lhnFSB6YyJDen-ZaJH:APA91bEKmvwKCtByb3INdua0ja5AN1CyZ6pb7RtC7YQ7sLopctfq6NzZRrFRGdhSJ3M1KU_0fcQiSyNcvUjkSfq2YSz-eqgrOsdmh84oiUhZzSZb-b-rAJDpTL_kHnYXn6T0CjMIaZ0y",
> "apns-priority": 5 }

Any help would be appreciated.